# Run MPI program without a X11 server?

Tags: mpi, x11, openmpi, xserver

I'm testing simple MPI programs locally on my Ubuntu Focal server (Open MPI 4.0.3). However whatever I run with `mpirun` it produces an annoying message `No protocol specified`. The problem appears to be related to the fact that `mpirun` is trying to connect to the X server. How can I disable this behavior so I can use `mpirun` without a X server ready? I primarily work over SSH (text-only, with tmux).

An example of what I'm doing:

```
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$ cat test.c
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    // This is a stub program
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$ mpicc test.c
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$ mpirun -np 2 a.out
No protocol specified
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$
```

---

**Update 1:** It appears to be related to LightDM and Xorg. The unwanted message goes away after `systemctl stop lightdm`. Alternatively, running Open MPI in a graphical terminal (connected via VNC or RDP (xrdp), both work) also eliminates the message, as `strace` shows that the connection to the X server is successful.

Comment: What's the full output of mpirun? Does it hang after printing "no protocol specified"?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi No, it doesn't hang and the MPI program proceeds normally.

Comment: `mpirun` is not an X11 application, nor is your program. Do you also get that message if you run `./a.out` or `mpirun -np 2 hostname`?

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes. The same message shows up with `./a.out` and `mpirun -np 2 /bin/ls`.

Comment: Sounds more like misconfigured system than an intrinsic problem with OMPI. Check the value of `$LD_PRELOAD` and look for environment variables starting with `OMPI_`. There are also two locations for user- and system-wide default OMPI MCA parameters, but I don't recall them right now.

Comment: @HristoIliev None of the environment variables you mentioned exist, nor does the user OMPI MCA parameter file. The system-wide is the stock one from the deb package.

Comment: I'm confused. If you are getting that message when you run `mpirun -np 2 /bin/ls` and when you run `./a.out`, then why aren't you getting it three times when you run `mpirun -np 2 a.out`? Could it be something that the shell is doing? Unset `DISPLAY` if set and see if it has any effect.

Comment: @HristoIliev I'm confused, too. Even though `$DISPLAY` is not set, it can still be seen via strace that Open MPI attempts to connect to a series of sockets like `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`, and receives the message from the socket (instead of generating it).

Comment: Sounds like something that the X11 client library would do, though not if `DISPLAY` is unset. I have never experienced such behaviour on behalf of Open MPI. It certainly has the option to launch the ranks in separate X terminals, but that is not something it does by default. Check the PAM configuration for weird session modules.

Comment: You can also `ldd` both mpirun and a.out. They might depend on X11 (dependent) libs that do funny things in the constructor. BTW, mpirun spawns tasks on the same host, right?