# Simple MPI program won't execute and is put to sleep mode (C++)

Tags: c++, mpi, mpic++

I am trying to run this simple MPI program with the `mpic++` compiler.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Initialize the MPI environment
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  
  // Get the number of processes
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
  
  // Get the rank of the process
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  
  // Get the name of the processor
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  int name_len;
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);
  
  // Print off a hello world message
  std::cout << "Hello world from processor" << processor_name << " rank" << world_rank << " out of " << world_size << "processors" << std::endl;

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I compile with `mpic++ main.cpp`
and when I execute `mpirun -n 2 ./a.out`
I get the warning `no protocol specified` which probably has to do with the fact that I am connected to a desktop via ssh and I am trying to run the program there, but most importantly, it does nothing.

If I type `top` there is no `a.out` listed and if I type  `ps aux | grep ./a.out` I get:

```
angelos+ 1925884  0.0  0.0  44664  7652 pts/9    S+   18:54   0:00 mpirun -n 2 ./a.out
```

Is this a dynamic linking problem or what? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881568/run-mpi-program-without-a-x11-server

Comment: @JacobFaib It is not my main concern. In his case, the program runs normally.

Comment: What if you grep for just `a.out` instead of `./a.out`?

Comment: @HristoIliev ```angelos+ 1937255  0.1  0.0  44664  7504 pts/10   S+   10:10   0:00 mpirun -n 2 ./a.out
``` and ```angelos+ 1937397  0.0  0.0  20532   732 pts/11   S+   10:10   0:00 grep --color=auto a.out
```

Comment: Restarting the desktop to which I ssh, seems to have solved the problem, at least for now :')